Laravel 11 Sanctum api/user returns 401 on first log in attempt when switching users on front end nuxt 3 SPA
I am currently developing an application using Laravel 11 and Sanctum as a backend API and Nuxt 3 as a front end SPA.
I've configured Laravel Santum to use SPA authentication (session and not token based authentication).
I have this working fine for the most part. I can log in, logout, log back in - reset passwords etc.; However if I log out as one user, then attempt to log in as a different user for the very first time I get a 401 unauthorized response when calling my api/user endpoint.
If I hit the login button again, it logs in fine and no further issues. Can anybody shed any light on why this is happening? I am thinking it's some sort of issue with my front end or backend somehow using my previous users session data on the first attempt but I cannot seem to resolve the problem.
My Login page:
  
  try {
    // Show loading message
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Please wait...',
      html: 'Your login is being processed.',
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      didOpen: () => {
        Swal.showLoading();
      },
    });

    // Fetch the CSRF token from Laravel Sanctum
    await fetch(`${backBase}/sanctum/csrf-cookie`, {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    // Collect form data
    const formData = {
      email: document.getElementById('email').value,
      password: document.getElementById('password').value,
    };

    const xsrfToken = getXsrfToken();

    // Submit the registration data to your API
    const response = await fetch(`${apiBase}/login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        ...(xsrfToken ? { 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': xsrfToken } : {}),
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
      // Dismiss the current Swal
      Swal.close();

      if (data.errors) {
        // Handle validation errors
        const errorMessages = Object.values(data.errors).map(fieldErrors => fieldErrors.join('<br>'));
        const formattedErrors = errorMessages.join('<br><br>');
        Swal.fire('Login Failed', formattedErrors, 'error');
      } else {
        // Handle other types of errors, such as incorrect credentials
        Swal.fire('Login Failed', data.message || 'An error occurred.', 'error');
      }

      console.error('Error Logging In:', data.message || data.errors);
      
    } else {

      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Success!',
        text: 'Login succesful!',
        icon: 'success',
      }).then(() => {
        navigateTo('/dashboard');
      });

      await useAuth(); // Call useAuth to update the auth store

      console.log('Login successful');

    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Dismiss the current Swal in case of network error or other exceptions
    Swal.close();
    
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Error!',
      text: 'Unable to log you in at this time. Please try again',
      icon: 'warning',
    });
  }
};

const getXsrfToken = () => {
  const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
  const xsrfTokenCookie = cookies.find(cookie => cookie.trim().startsWith('XSRF-TOKEN='));
  return xsrfTokenCookie ? decodeURIComponent(xsrfTokenCookie.split('=')[1]) : null;
};


After the successful log in response is received I call await useAuth() this is to make a call to my api/user endpoint and update the local Pinia store.

  const authStore = useAuthStore();

  try {

    console.log("Starting useAuth");

    // Fetch the CSRF token from Laravel Sanctum
    await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie`, {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    console.log("Getting xsrfToken");

    const xsrfToken = getXsrfToken();

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/user', { 

      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        ...(xsrfToken ? { 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': xsrfToken } : {}),
      },
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("USEAUTH RESPONSE GOOD STATUS" + response.status);
      console.log("USEAUTH RESPONSE GOOD DATA" + response.data);
      console.log("USEAUTH RESPONSE GOOD" + JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
      const userData = await response.json();
      authStore.setUser(userData);
    } else {
      console.log("USEAUTH RESPONSE BAD STATUS" + response.status);
      console.log("USEAUTH RESPONSE BAD DATA" + response.data);
      console.log("USEAUTH RESPONSE BAD" + JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
      authStore.clearUser();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Auth check failed', error);
  }

};


const getXsrfToken = () => {
  console.log("Running xsrfToken");
  const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
  const xsrfTokenCookie = cookies.find(cookie => cookie.trim().startsWith('XSRF-TOKEN='));
  return xsrfTokenCookie ? decodeURIComponent(xsrfTokenCookie.split('=')[1]) : null;
};

In my logout function on my backend I currently do this:
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout(); 

        $request->session()->invalidate(); // Invalidate the session
        $request->session()->regenerateToken(); // Regenerate the CSRF token

        // Clear cookies
        cookie()->forget('laravel_session');
        cookie()->forget('XSRF-TOKEN');

        Log::info('User logged out');

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Logged out successfully'], 200)->withCookie(
            Cookie::forget('laravel_session')
        )->withCookie(
            Cookie::forget('XSRF-TOKEN')
        );
    } 


As stated earlier, I am not sure this is a configuration issue with Sanctum as I can successfully make requests as normal throughout my application, it just seems to be an issue when trying to log in as a different user from the front end on the very first attempt.
Does anybody have any ideas or pointers on where to look to try and resolve this?
Many thanks,
Ste.
